Azure DevOps pipeline PowerShell task
I am using Azure DevOps pipeline and task 'AzurePowershell@5'. With that task I trigger script, which is on the repo- let's call it script X. Script X contains commands like 'Import-AzAutomationRunbook'. This command has parameter '-Path', which refers to a .ps1 script Y, which is suppose to be uploaded to Azure Runbook during pipeline run. The script Y sits on the same repo as script X.
Unfortunately, when I try to invoke script Y as parameter:
Import-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName `
                           -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                           -Name $Name `
                           -Path $scriptY `
                           -Type PowerShell

it gives me error like:
Cannot find path 'D:\a\1\s\scriptY.ps1' because it does not exist.
The 'Import' command is located at script X inside a loop- I m not sure if it matters (I think not).
My question is, how to properly refer to script Y inside script X, to be working as a parameter of command 'Import-AzAutomationRunbook'?
BR

Please edit your question and paste the relevant AzurePowershell@5 task.

Are you still facing the issue. @Vortex

The issue is with the file path to scriptY.ps1 PowerShell script as the path is not found or not valid.
There is a possibility of path conflict if you have multiple repositories referencing in the same Azure Devops pipelines. To avoid the conflict related to the path directory, you can use
Checkout flag in yaml script

Use checkout to configure how the pipeline checks out source code. Specify self, none, repository name, or repository resource.

checkout: self
Referring to theMSDoc, I have created below PowerShell script and was able to run the pipeline successfully as shown below.
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Import Runbook'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Jahnaviservice'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      $params = @{
          AutomationAccountName = 'autoccaro'
          ResourceGroupName     = 'caronew'
          Name                  = 'samplesc'
          Type                  = 'PowerShell'
          Path                  = 'samplesc.ps1'
      }
      Import-AzAutomationRunbook @params
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

Import-AzAutomationRunbook



